# What's the best template for writing a (serious) synthesis?

Tags: templates

I use LaTeX every day for writing syntheses (with lots of figures and mathjax). Would you have any good public, free template I can use for doing beautiful pages ? I only used report templates so far. Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with "beautiful pages"?

Comment: I can't study propely a synthesis if it's not really well organised, illustrated with the essential elements evidenced (by "fcolorbox" for instance)

Comment: mathjax is pretty much off-topic on this site.  Do you really mean that you're summarizing some theory with lots of figures and mathematical expressions?  I would expect that such a summary would depend so much on the theory that a template would be useless.  (And fcolorbox would tempt me to make things too distracting instead of explanatory.)

Comment: So you mean I shouldn't use a template at all ?

Comment: Your question is humongously vague: "synthesis", "mathjax", "good", "free", "template", "beautiful", "pages", and "report" all have shades of meaning that would affect the answer (some of those are more specific than others, but given how you've used some of the terms, I'm not entirely convinced on any of them).  Given all those possibilities, I'll go with "you shouldn't use a template at all".  If you're wanting better advice, then you'll need to make your question much more specific.

Comment: What are "syntheses"?  Use the `memoir` class and any additional packages that are appropriate.